# Does electric muscle stimulation help with sprains or strains?

Tags: workout, injury, muscle-recovery

Say you got a sprain or strain on your lower back, hamstrings, and  glutes, with my understanding, it contracts the muscles, if you were to workout while wearing these, can it help regenerate muscle tissue.

Comment: strains are for muscles, sprains are for connective tissue